# following navigation bar when scroll jquery

Tags: php, jquery, requirejs

i have a jquery for the bar following when scroll down/up but it has delay
CSS

```
#rightbar_scroll {position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;z-index: 10000; }

 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var jQuerysidebar   = jQuery("#rightbar_scroll"),
        jQuerywindow    = jQuery(window),
        offset     = jQuerysidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 20;
    jQuerywindow.scroll(function() {
        if (jQuerywindow.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: jQuerywindow.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            jQuerysidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });
});
```

i want it no delay, how do i add position like the box "Similar Questions" at the right side when ask question in this site?

Thank you, sorry my English not good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [jQuery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead jQuery.animate()

```
jQuerysidebar.css({
    marginTop: jQuerywindow.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the position of #rightbar_scroll to fixed, if the page is scrolled >= offset.top
And don't forget to change it back to absolute, if the page is scrolled back again...